# How to remove specific character from a string in pyspark?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to remove specific character from a string but not able to get any proper solution.
Could you please help me how to do this?

I am loading the data into dataframe using pyspark. One of the column having the extra character which i want to remove.

Example:

```
|"\""warfarin was discontinued 3 days ago and xarelto was started when the INR was 2.7, and now the INR is 5.8, should Xarelto be continued or stopped?"|
```

But in result i want only :

```
|"warfarin was discontinued 3 days ago and xarelto was started when the INR was 2.7, and now the INR is 5.8, should Xarelto be continued or stopped?"|
```

I am using below code to write dataframe into file:

```
df.repartition(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').mode('overwrite').save(output_path, escape='\"', sep='|',header='True',nullValue=None)
```

Comment: use regexp_replace in pyspark on that column

Answer (score 0):

Try the below to remove punctuation from the starting of your string

```
from string import punctuation
mystring = """\""warfarin was discontinued 3 days ago and xarelto was started when the INR was 2.7, and now the INR is 5.8, should Xarelto be continued or stopped?"""
print(mystring.lstrip(punctuation))
```

output:

```
'warfarin was discontinued 3 days ago and xarelto was started when the INR was 2.7, and now the INR is 5.8, should Xarelto be continued or stopped?'
```

Comment: Hi Jai.. Thank you for the respond. This problem is coming while saving the data into file. Is there any option in pyspark to avoid this kind of unnecessary characters?

Answer (score 0):

You can use some other escape characters instead of '\' you can change this to anything else. If you have option to save file to any other format prefer parquet (or orc) over csv.